# Replace values in numpy array containing NaN

Tags: python, numpy, nan

```
aa = np.array([2.0, np.NaN])
aa[aa>1.0] = np.NaN
```

On running the code above, I get the foll. warning, I understand the reason for this warning, but how to avoid it?

`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater`

Comment: Do you want to replace NaN values in numpy array or just eliminate `RuntimeWarning`? If the latter, `np.seterr(invalid='ignore')` is enough. Refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192637/runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-maximum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the indices of the valid ones (non - NaNs). First off, we will use these indices to index into the array and perform the comparison to get a mask and then again index into those indices with that mask to retrieve back the indices corresponding to original order. Using the original-ordered indices, we could then assign elements in the input array to `NaNs`.

Thus, an implementation/solution would be -

```
idx = np.flatnonzero(~np.isnan(aa))
aa[idx[aa[idx] > 1.0]] = np.nan
```

Sample run -

```
In [106]: aa  # Input array with NaNs
Out[106]: array([  0.,   3.,  nan,   0.,   9.,   6.,   6.,  nan,  18.,   6.])

In [107]: idx = np.flatnonzero(~np.isnan(aa)) # Store valid indices

In [108]: idx
Out[108]: array([0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9])

In [109]: aa[idx[aa[idx] > 1.0]] = np.nan # Do the assignment

In [110]: aa #  Verify
Out[110]: array([  0.,  nan,  nan,   0.,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan])
```

Comment: In Py3, comparisons with `np.nan` produce False without warnings.

Comment: Does this work for multidimensional arrays? I am getting errors because `idx` uses linear indexing.

Comment: @Darcy For multidim arrays, you would need to use `np.where` that would give us indices along all dims and then use those to index and assign.